# hide the keypad of the textfield and display datepicker

Tags: iphone

i have a form wher i need to enter the start date and end date to view the transactions.
when i set the focus on the textfirld, i can see the keypad, but behind it the datepicker is coming.
how am i remove the keypad and only show the datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with that myself and found the solution. You can do it this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// set delegate for date text field
    dateField.delegate = self;
}

// Display the picker instead of a keyboard
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self showDatePicker];
    return NO;

}
```

This assumes, that you have declared a method called showDatePicker, which handles the UIPicker display.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like instead of a standard keypad, you instead want to show your own datepicker view. I believe you can handle that by setting the delegate for your textfield then providing 
textFieldShouldBeginEditing.

// in viewWillAppear set the textfield delegate if needed

```
   ...
   myTextField.delegate = self;
   ...

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        // if date picker not in display, show it here...

        return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call [myTextField resignFirsrResponder] on some button click method or, for example, in textFieldShouldReturn delegate method. smth like that

> ```
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
>     [textField resignFirstResponder];
>     return YES;
> }
> ```

Comment: i dont want to add a button , and then dismiss the keypad.
simply on clicking the textfield it should display the datepicker

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn: delegate method called after "Return" button of keyboard was pressed.

Comment: you mean to say that every time i set the focus on the text field, the keypad will be shown, and when i press the return button, i will be shown the datepicker.

Comment: I mean that every time you will press return button, keyboard will hide. and after setting the focus to the text field it will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use these two links.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866

Comment: and

http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-searching-table-view.html

I spent hrs banging my head trying to get it to work and finally it worked.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, in viewController.h put the UITextFieldDelegate. After in viewDidLoad.

```
 txtFecha.delegate = self;

datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

self.txtFecha.inputView = datePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use **inputView**  and **inputAccessoryView** of UITextField.
Declare in .h file, and @synthesize in .m file.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar    *_accessoryView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *_datePickerView;
```

Connect them to File's Owner in .xib file, make sure that its out of the self.view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {   
        _dateOfBirthTextField.inputView = self._datePickerView;
        _dateOfBirthTextField.inputAccessoryView = self._toolbar;
    }
```

Also write function to fetch date from the picker

```
#pragma mark- UITextField with UIDatePicker-

- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
    _dateOfBirthTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", picker.date];
}

- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender {
    [_dateOfBirthTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Add dateChanged: IBAction on valueChanged: action of _datePicker. 
and doneEditing: IBAction on toolbar barbutton action.